# Нет плавного скроллинга в браузере в виртуальной машине

Tags: ubuntu, браузер, virtualbox, vmware, виртуальная-машина

Нет плавности скроллинга в браузере в гостевой Ubuntu 18.04.
Одинаковое поведение и в Ubuntu 16.04, как в Chrome, так и в Firefox, vbox, либо vmware.
Видео - nvidia, VMTools установлены, 3d ускорение - включено.
Насколько понимаю, установить проприетарный nvidia драйвер в гость систему нельзя.
Подскажите как решить проблему?

Comment: а он вообще должен быть? в смысле: он принципиально возможен в столь извращённой конфигурации?

Comment: Может быть и не должен, я не знаю), интересно почему в данном случае не должен, такая накладная операция? Предполагаю, что из-за невозможности установить проприетарный драйвер. Какие вы тут видите извращения?